# Unusual behavior of MultiActionController, Its not letting leave it's controll

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I'm using MultiActionCotroller for handling user details curd operations.
In Controller I'v define add, delete, update method and these methods referring different pages.
Every page then invoking different Controller(SimpleFormController) for performing their operation but when I'm trying to invoke different controller, its not going to that controller. Its again searching into the MultiActionController with the action path name of refered page.

Its not getting out from the MultiActionController, here I'm not understanding the behavior of the MultiActionController.

In my example, In the **add_details_form.jsp**, I'm defined action path name, that is "**details_path.htm**". and this is suppose to invoke "**AddCtrl**" controller but it's not going to AddCtrl but **UserMultiCtrl**.
Really I'm stuck here, I can't move forward.

I'm not familiar with annotation

I'v gone through many sites but I didn't get any...

I'v very high expectation from StackOverFlow of getting solution of it.

Thanks in advance

Here is my code

> Index.jsp

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="multiaction/add.htm">Add User Details</a><br>
    </li>
    <li><a href="multiaction/update.htm">Update User Details</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="multiaction/delete.htm">Delete User Details</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

> UserMultiCtrl

```
public class UserMultiCtrl extends MultiActionController {

public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("add_details_form");
    return mav;
}

public ModelAndView update(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("update_details_form");
    return mav;
}

public ModelAndView delete(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("delete_details_form");
    return mav;
}
```

}

> Spring-Servlet.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="/multiaction/*.htm" class="ctrlPack9.UserMultiCtrl">
    <property name="methodNameResolver" >
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.InternalPathMethodNameResolver" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="/details_path.htm" class="ctrlPack9.AddCtrl">
    <property name="commandClass" value="hiberPack9.UserDetails"/>
    <property name="commandName" value="userDetails"/>
    <property name="formView" value="add_details_form"/>
    <property name="successView" value="userDetails_list"/>
</bean>
```

> add_details_form.jsp

```
<form:form action="details_path.htm"  commandName="userDetails" method="POST">
    User Name:<input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
    Address:<input type="text" name="address" /><br/>
    Age:<input type="text" name="age" /><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form:form>
```

> AddCtrl.java

```
public class AddCtrl extends SimpleFormController {
private DetailsJB djb;

public void setDjb(DetailsJB djb) {
    this.djb = djb;
}

@Override
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors)
        throws Exception {
    UserDetails detail = (UserDetails) command;
    djb.store(detail);
    List userDetails = djb.retrive();
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("userDetails", userDetails);
    mav.setViewName("userDetails_list");
    System.out.println("in addctrl onSubmit ");
    return mav;
}
```

}

I got the point where is the actual problem.
There is nothing to do with spring-servlet.xml we can do url mapping in any manner.

when any request go to the MultilActionController(UserMultiCtrl) it adds "multiaction" into the url heading that why when I'm try to invoke **AddCtrl** with action path name **details_path.htm**. It is appended by the suffix **multiaction** in the url. So it is searching into the MultilActionController(UserMultiCtrl) and its not getting any appropriate method.

If anyone know, how to resolve this url in url bar then I can get my solution.
Otherwise I've to append **multiaction** suffix to every action path and I don't want to do.

Comment: Show how the handlermappings are defined.

Comment: Did you try the below two scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1:
If you do not have handler mapping specified explicitly, dispatcher servlet provides [BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping.html) by default. '/' is not a valid character in the "id" attribute of xml bean definitions.
In BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping, mapping is done from URLs to beans with names that start with a slash("/") and not ids. I don't see name attribute specified in your controller definitions.

So change your controller definitions as:

```
    <bean name="/multiaction/*.htm" class="ctrlPack9.UserMultiCtrl">
        ...
    </bean>

    <bean name="/details_path.htm" class="ctrlPack9.AddCtrl">
        ...
    </bean>
```

Scenario 2:
If you do not want to rely on default BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping, define a SimpleUrlHandlerMapping as:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <value>
                /multiaction/*.htm=userMultiCtrl
                /details_path.htm=addCtrl
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userMultiCtrl" name="userMultiCtrl" class="ctrlPack9.UserMultiCtrl">
            ...
    </bean>

    <bean id="addCtrl" name="addCtrl" class="ctrlPack9.AddCtrl">
        <property name="commandClass" value="hiberPack9.UserDetails"/>
        <property name="commandName" value="userDetails"/>
        <property name="formView" value="add_details_form"/>
        <property name="successView" value="userDetails_list"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering n sorry for late.I tried both but It's not working. "/" works in id in another project. I'm not very familiar with SimpleUrlHandlerMapping so If you can elaborate it then I hope I'll find out url mapping problem.(any link would be appreciated)

Comment: I studied on SimpleUrlHandlerMapping. but I think problem with MultiActionController, it's not letting go control from it's control. Error msg is like `May 6, 2014 6:45:35 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound handleNoSuchRequestHandlingMethod
WARNING: No request handling method with name 'details_path' in class [ctrlPack9.UserMultiCtrl]`

Comment: @userBI refactor your controller bean definitions as per above 2 scenarios in Spring-Servlet.xml each time and check. Moreover I changed only xml file and not in class or jsp. So make sure you have the same what you have shown in the question.